# APNS mis-triggering the push notifications to some devices

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I'm encountered a strange issue now..

The problem is that even though the central server which in charge of pushing notifications to APNS using APNS-PHP (Open source push sending management built on top of PHP language.) didn't fire duplicated message, the devices showing same messages that previously gotten from the APNS over and over.

The differences that may distinguish with normal messages are as follows:

- sound parameter not affected on the problematic message. (Even though I configured custom sound for each message, the duplicated message sounds default.)
- time value is inappropriately displayed on iphone standby screen like the following example:

---

A app: this is the push                  4 hours ago

B app: blah blah..                       3 mins ago

A app: take my present:xxx...            4 mins ago

A app: message arrived:xx..              4 mins ago

B app: lalala...                         7 mins ago

---

As you can see in above, most recent message should be listed on top but the duplicated message that is previously arrived couple times is pops up again with a sound and vibration as that of normal messages but the time is precisely displayed: 4 hours ago.

I know this situation is not makes sense at all but please let me know anything that could help to find a clue on this issue.

Thank you in advance